# SARIMA assumptions

Tags: linear-regression, arima

Under what assumptions, can the predictions of the SARIMA model be considered valid forecasts?

Specifically, when using auto-arima on thousands of time series (all time series are similar to each other and arise from the same population), I am unable to check for normality of errors or PACF for each sarima model.

Are there any checks I can perform on one time series data set to verify the validity of a SARIMA model.